# How to reiterate json response to extract a token and to make a restapi call with for-each activity

Tags: rest, api, azure-data-factory

i am using Copy Data activity(Can't use Web activity due to security reasons) to connect to Rest API(source) (via REST dataset)and I get a response in json format as shown below which is what i need, only that this is the first page and there are many other pages that i need to retrieve. The retrieved information is then saved in SQL database table (destination). In process to retrieve the next pages i need to extract the token from "continuationToken" and send it back to my REST dataset as an dynamic value. Not sure if this is the correct way but gave it a try.

```
[  
   {  
      "pagedResponse":[  
         {  
            "docType":"current",
            "orgNumber":"98789765",
            "persons":[  

            ],
            "clientId":43533,
            "name":null,
            "clientResponsible":{
               "id":null,
               "name":null
            }
         }
      ],
      "continuationToken":{  
         "token":"-RID:Om1+ANeDbNMWASEAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:10#ISrV:2#IEO:6554436",
         "range":{  
            "min":"",
            "max":"05C1DFFFFFFFFFFC"
         }
      }
   }
]
```

I tried to run some test by saving the json response as a file. Created Lookup activity(Lookup1) to read in the json file and in the then created a for-each activity and in the items i  added a dynamic content 
`@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].continuationToken`
        but got this error message.:

```
{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an 
     array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "ForEach1"
}
```

expected result was:

`"token":"-RID:Om1+ANeDbNMWASEAAAAAAAAA==#RT:1#TRC:10#ISrV:2#IEO:6554436",
             "range":{"min":"","max":"05C1DFFFFFFFFFFC"}`

Comment: You don't have any index to give for the ForEach loop. Can you try to do a for each for example to clientId? For Each `@activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].pagedResponse.clientId`. If this work's you can think about other approach to your problem but the path will be something to give the for each statment.

Comment: @Praetorian1995 thank you for the response, i will give it a try.

Comment: I'm waiting for your feedback :)

Comment: Hi, tried it and got this error{
    "errorCode": "InvalidTemplate",
    "message": "The expression 'length(activity('Lookup1').output.value[0].pagedResponse.clientId)' cannot be evaluated because property 'clientId' cannot be selected. Array elements can only be selected using an integer index.",
    "failureType": "UserError",
    "target": "ForEach1"
}

Comment: As you can see it need an integer index. You client Id is an integer but its values are in the pagedResponse array. So you need to add some type of index to your json so your forEach expression can be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

I think your solution mentioned in the question should work.I suppose that you want to know whether the `continuationToken` is null so that the loop should be ended,so you use `length` function.However,according to the error message:`The function 'length' expects its parameter to be an array or a string. The provided value is of type 'Object'.` It is stated in the document clearly:

[image]

Then `continuationToken` is an object,should be used with `empty` function:

[image]